# android navigation view - clipped drawer

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-navigationview

I follow the [google drawer spec](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

And I use the default style "NavigationView" class in `android-support-design library`, the drawer will be the "full-height" style:
[image]

But actually I need the "clipped" drawer:
[image]

How to make the clipped drawer?
Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

**edit:** .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<!-- include your content layout -->

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/homepage"
                android:name="com.technotalkative.navigationviewdemo.MyFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!-- Navigation view -->

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/topMargin"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Please put your .xml file.

Comment: Here is my layout: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Grnk8LmhEcWjVzclphRmxHcTA/view?usp=sharing
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I edited my code, may it works for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">


        </FrameLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```